# Changing a Realm list in swift

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I have a model looking like this

```
class TodoList: Object {
   dynamic var listName: String = ""
   let doneItems = List<Item>()
   let notDoneItems = List<Item>()
}
```

I want to move items from doneItems to notDoneItems. My code looked like this:

```
func doneAnItem(item: Item, todoList: TodoList) {
    let realm = try! Realm()

    try! realm.write {
        if let itemIndex = todoList.unpickedItems.index(of: item) {
            todoList.notDoneItems.remove(objectAtIndex: itemIndex)
            todoList.doneItems.append(item)
        }
    }
}
```

But it looks like when I run this function, the todoList.notDoneItems and doneItems is not updated? How should I do that? I know I can use a bool on the done items, but I have to do it this way in this case.

Comment: Try change the `listName ` and see if it updated? Your code look correct, the problem may lie elsewhere, also try refetch the object after update

Comment: When printing the todoList, I can actually see it being updated. So maybe the issue is elsewhere. The problem is that when I have removed two or three, it will crash on if let itemIndex = todoList.... "@throw RLMException(@"Object has been deleted or invalidated");"

Comment: It sounds like you need to share more information since the snippet you've shared doesn't demonstrate the problem.

Comment: I found out the issue, I tried to remove an already removed item. So the item was already invalidated.